# Anyone know how to implements the effect like Unfold(which is a app in iphone ) in android?

Tags: java, android, iphone, 3d

[image: The effect is like this]

How can I implement this effect ? Any suggestion will be helpful for me :)

Comment: Specifically as a lock screen or just an animation?

Comment: I will look into it, it would be an interesting project. I have seen the source for doing something like this on github before. Granted it was not for Android, but the source was mostly mathematical (lots of trig) so the principles should easily translate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,and I will be waiting for your good news ：）

Comment: Please post a Link here for all who are waiting. Thanks! :)

Comment: Why not just 3 textured rectangles in OpenGL ?

Comment: Now you can find it here:https://github.com/tibi1712/FoldingNavigationDrawer-Android