# How can I make a layout smootly fade in/appear together with all the children?

Tags: java, android, animation, android-fragments, android-linearlayout

I have a a layout part of another layout that I make visible as follows:

```
AlphaAnimation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);  
animation.setDuration(4000);  
myLayout.setAnimation(animation);  
myLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

In my example with the animation the linear layout appears (the `myLayout`) and the text inside the `myLayout` (which has `TextViews`) fades in.
Is there a way to make both the `myLayout` and the children `TextViews` fade in?

**Update:**
The problem is that when I set the animation on the parent layout, it is the children that appear slowly according to the animation.
So I have:

`<LinearLayout 

      android:id="@+id/parent” 

      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 

      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

      android:layout_below="@id/someElement” 

      android:layout_marginTop=“5dp" 

      android:visibility="gone"         >                       

         <TextView 

                  android:id="@+id/child” 

                  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 

                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

                  android:textSize=“20sp” 

                  android:textColor="@color/red” 

                  android:gravity="center_vertical" 

                  android:visibility="gone"                  

              />
         </LinearLayout>`

and the parent pops down fast and the children text appears slowly.
What I would like is the parent to smoothly pop down and the child to appear also slowly

Comment: Can you link an animation with this page animation?

Comment: @oorosco:It is something that I have noticed and thought it was very smooth transition. But can't remember where. I thought it might be well known approach but could not find it google because don't know how it is called

Comment: I'm going to need a concrete example or at least a better explanation to help you out with 1

Comment: @oorosco:Ah...I have seen in on IPhone :-( --->  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756158/anyone-know-how-to-implements-the-effect-like-unfoldwhich-is-a-app-in-iphone

Comment: @oorosco:Can it be done without extra libraries?

Comment: eh... this is a bit complicated, I have no concrete knowledge as to how to implement this... perhaps using some 3d library, map the canvas onto the face of a 3d object? This is definitely more complicated then you'd think. Some more thoughts are going to be pushed to my answer down below

Answer (score 0):

My answers

1) Not sure 100% but if you don't want to do this using a complicated path, probably off some equation you yourself would create to do something like this: [Android -- Is it possible to warp a TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178659/android-is-it-possible-to-warp-a-textview)
^ Excerpt:

```
@Override onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    Path mPath = new Path();
    mPath.addCircle(x, y, 200, Path.Direction.CW);
    canvas.drawTextOnPath(textToDraw, mPath, textX, textY, paint);
}
```

Or this..

Step 1: [converting a canvas into bitmap image in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013725/converting-a-canvas-into-bitmap-image-in-android)
step 2:
[Android: how to warp images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779669/android-how-to-warp-images)

So basically make a bitmap from a canvas of your view, skew that image 
2) If i understand correctly, you want to fade in the parent, then fade in the children... soo...

```
private void doAnimation(){

    mLinearLayout.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(500);

    View child;
    for(int i=0; i< mLinearLayout.getChildCount(); i++){
        child = mLinearLayout.getChildAt(i);
        child.animate().setStartDelay(250)
                .alpha(1)
                .setDuration(750);
    }

}
```

Does this help?

Comment: I did `myLayout.animate().alpha(1.0f).setDuration(500); textView.animate().setStartDelay(250).alpha(1.0f).setDuration(1000); textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` but nothing shows up now. Before I had the problem that the parent showed up first faster but now nothing is visible

Comment: can you post your sourecode in your question up top? I'm having trouble putting what you're doing into my head :P

Comment: @Jim anyways let me know when you get a chance to post it